# Spring DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection targetInvocationException

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, invocationtargetexception

I am new to Spring and have encountered a perplexing error.

On line 423 of JDBCTemplate.class I am experiencing a TargetInvocationException after the releaseConnection method finishes. In other words --

I am doing a step though using eclipse.
After I return from releaseConnection and try and step over line 423 the TIE is triggered. The target is null so I am getting no info about what has happened.

Any tips on how to resolve this?

What further info would help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this, you likely have a deeper error. Check the JUnit stack trace to see what's coming out. In my case this was a null pointer error --- or a series of them that were hidden from me as they didn't show up until long after I'd failed to set a fields. The error however, was quite cryptic and the timing for the TIE was very strange. What I still don't understand is why the exception was thrown as I stepped over an instruction which appeared to have executed successfully.